# Tag I created disappear few days after

Tags: support, tags

I created tag [jmeter-3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter-3.3) 4 days ago. I also added tag wiki on it and I asked questions with this tag.

Today I don't see tag exists at all and it was removed from my questions.

How can the tag removed so fast and if you know why?

Comment: Why did you create this tag? What is so unique about version 3.3 of jmeter that it merits its own tag? In general, we try to avoid version-specific tags, and *certainly* minor version tags.

Comment: It has specific bugs for example.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean 3.2 whose tag wiki you edited? The system wouldn't have allowed you to create the tag you mention as non mods aren't allowed to create tags that look like version numbered stuff.

Comment: I created few months ago jmeter-3.2 tag, before 4 days I created jmeter-3.3 tag.

Comment: The bar for creating tags for dot-versions of things should be **very** high.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone probably took it upon themselves to burninate the tag. The [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071) allows for it without a meta post, if the tag includes less than 50 questions, and at least one other community member agrees, which probably was true for this case.

If you really want the tag to persist, open up a topic on Meta making your case why this tag is useful. If there's community consensus that the tag is useful, it probably won't get burninated again.

Comment: I already have privileges to create tags, you mean if tag burninated you can't reopen it? because it can be burninate once more even after community consensus

Comment: You can just create it again, and then someone can just burninate it again, but you __really should not__ do that. If a tag gets burninated, that  means someone has an objection to the tag existing (usually a strong one, someone put in some effort removing it). Obviously, you want it to exist. That's a conflict, which should be resolved by community consensus.